# Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

Trying to update this for the new provider - changed the first builder to create, but it give a no return error.  Thank you

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => UserRepository.instance(),
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, UserRepository user, _) {
          switch (user.status) {
            case Status.Uninitialized:
              return Splash();
            case Status.Unauthenticated:
            case Status.Authenticating:
              return LoginPage();
            case Status.Authenticated:
              return UserInfoPage(user: user.user);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

user_respository

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:implulsnew/model/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:implulsnew/login_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => UserRepository.instance(),
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, UserRepository user, _) {
          switch (user.status) {
            case Status.Uninitialized:
              return Splash();
            case Status.Unauthenticated:
            case Status.Authenticating:
              return LoginPage();
            case Status.Authenticated:
              return UserInfoPage(user: user.user);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserInfoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final FirebaseUser user;

  const UserInfoPage({Key key, this.user}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("User Info"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(user.email),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("SIGN OUT"),
              onPressed: () => Provider.of<UserRepository>(context).signOut(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Splash Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a `no return error`? Does changin it to `Consumer<UserRepository>` makes it work?

Comment: please post the code of UserRepository

Comment: Consumer<UserRepository> / Did not fix.  Exact message - This function has a return type 'Widget", but doesn't end with a return statment.

Comment: Try adding a `default` case to your `switch`, you always have to return something.

Comment: thanks worked well